# Rails: unit test fails with "No such file or directory....database.yml" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

When I execute a Rails unit test from the command line (as suggested [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#running-tests)) such as

```
ruby unit/test_model.rb
```

...I get this error:

```
No such file or directory - .../test/config/database.yml (Errno::ENOENT)
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one possible solution [here](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=37791).  From the project root directory, run:

```
ruby -Itest test/unit/test_model.rb
```